# Seekable html5 audio Uncaught Error: IndexSizeError: DOM Exception 1

Tags: javascript, html, flask, html5-audio, soundmanager2

I was having an issue trying to use the HTML5  API (also with SoundManager2). When trying to find the duration of a song so that I could make a progress bar as the song was playing. I kept running into the following error in the console:

```
Uncaught Error: IndexSizeError: DOM Exception 1
```

Here's the code used get the progress:

```
<a href="/uploads/song_71.mp3" class="song" id="song_71"></a>
<audio id="song" preload="auto" src=""></audio>

<script>

  var song = document.getElementById("song");
  song.addEventListener("timeupdate", function(){
    var end = this.seekable.end(0),
        curr = this.currentTime,
        prog = (curr / end) * 100;

    console.log(this.currentTime, this.duration)
  })

  song.play()

  document.getElementById("play_song").addEventListener("click", function(e){    
    var song_file = this.href;
    song.src = song_file
    song.play()

    if(e){ e.preventDefault(); }
    return false;
  })

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This was unbelievably frustrating and seeing as I could not find any help online I decided to post my answer. I'm sure this is probably a very specific issue I was running into but wouldn't be surprised if others were having this problem. I was using the Flask developemnt server which was not sending along the proper headers/mimetypes for MP3. Seeing as I was using this [shortcut function](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#flask.send_from_directory):

```
@app.route('/uploads/<path:filename>')
def download_file(filename):
    return send_from_directory(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename)
```

Once I moved my files to the live server (where I have Apache serving static files directly) the error was eradicated. Hope this helps some other poor soul :-)